# jpeg image taking long time to load in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, jpeg

I have developed an application in blackberry in which I provided a functionality to load image..but when image is set it does not appear on the screen till the light of the phone is on and later once light goes off and light is made on image appears.

I want to know why image takes long time to load or there could be a problem with image refresh... and what could be the possible solution to reduce the image load time or refresh time..?

Comment: Can you provide the code where the image is set?  Like Max answered below, it might be an issue of the display not refreshing but if you're using a BitmapField then it should automatically invalidate itself when you set the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

The display of the Blackberry is pretty small. Maybe your image is huge in comparison, so the poor device has to wade through lots of data (and has to throw away most of it). Try to create a thumbnail of the image when the app sees the original image for the first time in exactly the same resolution as the display of the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refresh image after loading it to screen:

```
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(
        new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                bitmapField.invalidate();
    }});
```